# Firebase Dynamic link no longer working with iOS app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have an augmented reality app that utilizes the dynamic link feature of firebase to transition between web app and mobile app.  This has been working seamlessly for the past couple of years, but has started causing an issue in the latest release we created in the past few weeks.  When the user taps on the button on the web app which contains the dynamic link to transition to the mobile app, if the user does not have the app install they will see the 'Open link in app' page and if they tap OPEN it takes them to the appropriate app store (apple or google) to download the app, this is fine.  However, after downloading the app if they tap on another link it takes them back to the 'Open link in app' page, as though they do not have the app installed.

We've tested numerous scenarios but if you restart the iPhone it will resolve the issue so it is almost as though a restart clears some sort of cache on the device and it then recognizes the app is installed.

Again, this was working perfectly and still is working on Android so it is limited to iOS and possibly may be related to iOS 13.3.1, I cannot say for sure.

Has anyone else seen this issue and have you been able to resolve it?  The app is built in unity and uses firebase for dynamic links and push notifications.

I would appreciate any advice you can offer?